# Compare the speed at which $(\bar{X})^2$ converges to zero to the speed at which $\sqrt{n}$ diverges to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

## Setup

Assume the following formation
$$
\bar{X} \overset{P}{\to} 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty.
$$

## Lemma

We want to show
$$
\sqrt{n}\cdot\left(\bar{X}\right)^2 \overset{P}{\to} 0.
$$
This is indeterminate form ($\infty \times 0$).

It seems to me that the sample mean would win because it is sensibly multiplied twice by something that converges to zero, but how can this be shown mathematically?

---

## Background

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. $N(\xi, \sigma^2)$ and consider the problem of simultaneously estimating or testing $\xi$ and $\sigma^2$. Then, we are interested in the joint distribution of
$$
Y_1 := \frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\xi)}{\sigma}\text{ and }Y_2 := \sqrt{n} \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n\sigma^2}-1\right).
$$
Since this distribution is independent of $\xi$ and $\sigma$, suppose that $\xi = 0$.
By bivariate CLT,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}\bar{X}}{\sigma}\text{ and }\sqrt{n} \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n\sigma^2}-1\right)
$$
are asymptotically independently distributed according to $N(0, 1)$ and $N(0, 2)$, respectively.
At this point, **if the Lemma holds**, we can get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Y_1 \\ Y_2
\end{pmatrix}\overset{d}{\to}
N_2\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\right)
$$
from Slutsky's theorem.

Comment: Your assumption that $X_i$ has finite variance seems stronger than $\bar{X} \overset{P}{\to} 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I assume the following:$(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ is a random iid sample with $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = 0, \text{Var}(X_i) = \sigma^2 < \infty$.

For $\epsilon > 0$, by the Markov's inequality, we have
$$
    \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}(\bar{X})^2 > \epsilon) \le \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\epsilon}\mathbb{E}[(\bar{X})^2]
$$
But,
$$
    \mathbb{E}[(\bar{X})^2] = \text{Var}(\bar{X}) = \dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}
$$
Thus,
$$
    \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}(\bar{X})^2 > \epsilon) \le \dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{n}\epsilon} \rightarrow 0, \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty
$$